# Setting bash aliases for IRB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, bash

So every morning to boot up my server , I need to do the following tasks..

```
>> sunspot-solr stop
>> sunspot-solr start
>> script/console
>> Organization.reindex
>> Event.reindex
>> Deal.reindex
>> exit
>> script/server
```

Is there any way I can make a shortcut in my ~/.profile as an alias to perform all this for me without me typing it everyday?

Like this though it doesn't work ?

```
alias blam='cur && sunspot-solr stop && sunspot-solr start && script/console && Organization.reindex && Event.reindex && Deal.reindex && exit && script/server'
```

Comment: why not put it in a script and call it from cron?

Comment: Why don't you write a shell script? aliases are ok for simple things but not for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will ease some of the pain?

```
#Rakefile
desc "Reindex the organizations, events, and deals Solr indexes."
task :reindex => :environment do
  Organization.reindex
  Event.reindex
  Deal.reindex
end
```

Then every morning run

```
> sunspot-solr stop
> sunspot-solr start
> rake reindex
> script/server
```

Comment: Would those commands work even though I'm not invoking script/console?

Comment: ** Invoke reindex (first_time)
** Execute reindex
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Organization

Comment: Edited. Need to declare that this task depends on the Rails-defined task `environment`. Use `task :reindex => :environment do ... end`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first StackOverflow post and it's a old question, but I felt I could contribute somehow :D
Rebuilding the Solr index periodically is a very expensive task, you should avoid doing things like this in production! What you are looking for can be best achieved in three ways:

1 - edit you sunspot.yml and add the line

`auto_commit_after_request = true`

This will tell sunspot to update the index **everytime** a new model entry is saved (or deleted). This will keep your index updated but can be expensive.

2 - create a rake task (can be run with cron on in a DelayedJob worker) like this

`task :update_index => :environment do 

  Sunspot.commit_if_dirty 

end`

This is far less expensive than doing a commit after every model update, but bear in mind that this introduces the problem of eventual consistency to your index, which is fine for adds but can be nasty for deletes: it will generate orphan entries in your index. This is also a problem with the third way to solve this problem ->

3 - edit your solrconfig.xml file and set the `autoCommit` feature with a `maxTime` an arbitrary interval between commits (remember to use times in miliseconds). 5 minutes would be nice for most applications, but you should test this yourself.

Hope this helps!